# Show that for a properly embedded submanifold the manifold and topogoical boundary coincide

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, submanifold

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $M\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$. Let $\partial M$ and $M^\circ$ denote the manifold boundary and interior and $\operatorname{Bd}M$ and $\operatorname{Int}M$ denote the topological boundary and interior of $M$, respectively.

> How can we show that $\partial M=\operatorname{Bd}M$ and $M^\circ=\operatorname{Int}M$?

Note that $M$ being properly empedded into $\mathbb R^d$ is equivalent to $M$ being $\mathbb R^d$-closed. So, $\operatorname{Bd}M=M\setminus\operatorname{Int}M$.

Let $x\in\partial M$. In order to prove $x\in\operatorname{Bd}M$, all we need to show is that every neighborhood of $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $M^c$.

There is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from an $M$-open neighborhood $\Omega$ of $x$ onto an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb H^d:=\mathbb R^{d-1}\times[0,\infty)$ and $$u:=\phi(x)\in\partial\mathbb H^d=\mathbb R^{d-1}\times\{0\}\tag1.$$ Since $U$ is $\mathbb H^d$-open, $$U=V\cap\mathbb H^d\tag2$$ for some open subset $V$ of $\mathbb R^d$ and since $V$ is $\mathbb R^d$-open, $$B_\varepsilon(u)\subseteq V\tag3$$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Now, clearly, $$B_\varepsilon(u)\cap\left(\mathbb R^d\setminus\mathbb H^d\right)\ne\emptyset\tag4.$$

> But how can we conclude?

Note that $$\phi=\left.\tilde\phi\right|_\Omega\tag5$$ for some $\tilde\phi\in C^1(O,\mathbb R^d)$ for some $\mathbb R^d$-open neighborhood $O$ of $\Omega$.

Comment: +1. Good question. I thought before your question that a smooth manifold with boundary is a smooth Hausdorff, locally Euclidean topological space with boundary but it is not true!!

Comment: Do you know what is the problem with the above definition?

Answer (score 0):

As Jack Lee  noted in his

*Lee, John M.*, [**Introduction to smooth manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5), Graduate Texts in Mathematics 218. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4419-9981-8/hbk; 978-1-4419-9982-5/ebook). xvi, 708 p. (2013). [ZBL1258.53002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1258.53002).

on page 26:

> Be careful to observe the distinction between these new definitions of the terms
> boundary and interior and their usage to refer to the boundary and interior of a subset
> of a topological space. A manifold with boundary may have nonempty boundary
> in this new sense, irrespective of whether it has a boundary as a subset of some other
> topological space. If we need to emphasize the difference between the two notions
> of boundary, we will use the terms topological boundary and manifold boundary
> as appropriate. For example, the closed unit ball $\overline{\Bbb B}^n$
> is a manifold with boundary, whose manifold boundary is $\Bbb S^{n-1}$. Its topological boundary as
> a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ happens to be the sphere as well. However, if we think of $\overline{\Bbb B}^n$ as
> a topological space in its own right, then as a subset of itself, it has empty topological
> boundary. And if we think of it as a subset of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ (considering $\Bbb R^n$ as a
> subset of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ in the obvious way), its topological boundary is all of $\overline{\Bbb B}^n$. Note that
> $\Bbb H^n$ is itself a manifold with boundary, and its manifold boundary is the same as its
> topological boundary as a subset of $\Bbb R^n$. Every interval in $\Bbb R$ is a 1-manifold with
> boundary, whose manifold boundary consists of its endpoints (if any).

> The nomenclature for manifolds with boundary is traditional and well established,
> but it must be used with care. Despite their name, manifolds with boundary
> are not in general manifolds, because boundary points do not have locally Euclidean
> neighborhoods.

Comment: In a manifold with boundary, each point is locally diffeomorphic to a half space $H$. Interior points are locally diffeomorphic to $H^\circ$ and boundary points are mapped to $\partial H$. However, I'm not sure how this is related to my question. Maybe you got it wrong? I want to prove that the topological boundary/interior and manifold boundary/interior coincide when $M$, as in the question, is properly embedded.

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong. Maybe. Please answer to this: What is the boundary of 2-disk as subset (and I think it  is properly embedded) of Euclidean plane?